# Finding/approximating possible antiderivative given d/dx at multiple points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I am given multiple x values and the derivative of f(x) at each point. Ex: d/d(0) = 0, d/d(2) = 2, d/d(3) = 3. How do I find a function with these derivatives?

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ then $f'(x)=x$. So $f'(0)=0,f'(2)=2,f'(3)=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find a [polynomial that has those values at those places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). That is always possible, for a finite number of data points. In your case, $f(x)=x$ obviously fits. There are infinitely many other possibilities.

Then integrate that polynomial. In your case, $F(x)=\frac 12x^2+C$ works, for any constant value $C$.

---

Finding a polynomial that has the given values at the given places can be done with Lagrange polynomials and is explained in the link above. Here is how it is applied in your particular case.

You want $f(0)=0,\ f(2)=2,\ f(3)=3$, three points. The unique polynomial of degree at most $3-1$ giving these three points is

$$0\cdot\frac{x-2}{0-2}\cdot\frac{x-3}{0-3}
 +2\cdot\frac{x-0}{2-0}\cdot\frac{x-3}{2-3}
 +3\cdot\frac{x-0}{3-0}\cdot\frac{x-2}{3-2}$$
$$=0+(-1)(x^2-3x)+(1)(x^2-2x)$$
$$=x$$

You see the first expression has three terms, one for each given point. The $k$'th term is set up so substituting the $k$'th $x$-value there gives the $k$'th $y$-value (which is the coefficient out front of the term) and substituting any other given $x$-value there gives zero. Adding all those terms gives us the desired polynomial.

If you want yet another polynomial, add a fourth point that does not conflict in its $x$-value with the other given points, and do that process again. As I said, there are infinitely many possibilities, but the formula I gave is the polynomial of lowest degree that works.

There are other ways to get the same polynomial that are easier to compute, but it is also more difficult to understand how they work.

Comment: How do you "find a polynomial that has those values at those places"?